# Accessing a PHP array object(stdClass) values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I am using WordPress' native function [get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)
and it returns this array with an object inside:

```
array (size=2)
  157 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'term_id' => int 157
      public 'name' => string 'Entertainment' (length=13)
      public 'slug' => string 'entertainment' (length=13)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 157
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 1
      public 'object_id' => int 644
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  151 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'term_id' => int 151
      public 'name' => string 'Featured' (length=8)
      public 'slug' => string 'featured' (length=8)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 151
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 1
      public 'object_id' => int 644
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

How do I access

```
  public 'name' => string 'Featured' (length=8)
```

This works

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $test = $term->name;
    echo $test;
}
```

This does not work:

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
    $term = $terms->name;
    echo $term;
}
```

nor does this work

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
    $term = $terms[0]->name;
    //$term = $terms[1]->name;
    //$term = $terms[157]->name; // works but not reliable
    echo $term;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Because you aren't using the index to access the aray member you want. Try `$term = $terms[$i]->name;`

Comment: why this must works^)?

Comment: I did that and using terms[157] works but isnt that subject to change? I just want the first spot in the array. terms[0]->name does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_the_terms` is returning an array, which is indexed by the `term_id` of each element.

That is why `$terms[157]` and `$terms[151]` are working as you expect. See the [PHP reference on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) for details of this behavior.

Your best bet is to stick with the built in `foreach` which works as stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks @dehrg but see my comment above. This is one of the first things I've tried in the for loop.

Comment: Yes the point of the for loop is to limit the amount of categories displayed. In this case only 2.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the foreach? Given that the function is returning an array with odd indices, that seems like your best bet.

Comment: Ok, and just build in the incrementing var to limit the loop? But I'm more concerned with why terms[0] or terms[1] won't work.

Comment: Edited to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you are trying to access name directly within the array, not the `stdclass` objects.

You need to use the `$i` variable as the index of the array.

```
for ($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
    $term = $terms[$i]->name;
    echo $term;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function using the **wp_parse_args** system to manage its single **$args** argument, which could be given whatever values you wanted. In this case $args stores detailed display overrides, a pattern found in many WordPress functions.

```
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $term->name );
echo $arg[157]['term_id']; //output 157
echo $arg[157]['name'];  //output Entertainment
```

works fine for me more detail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args